# Link against node.js in simple c++ program

Tags: c++, node.js, linker-errors

We are trying to use `node.js` in a C++ project and thus cloned the `nodejs/node` repository, that is linked from the Node.js documentation (chapter [C++ embedder API](https://nodejs.org/api/embedding.html)).

We sucessfully built `nodejs` by running:

```
./configure
make -j4
```

Then we created a simple `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

project(v8-cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(NODE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/node)

set(HEADERS

)

set(SOURCES

)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS
 ${NODE_DIR}/deps/v8/include/
 ${NODE_DIR}/deps/uv/include/

 ${NODE_DIR}/src/
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
 main.cpp
 ${HEADERS}
 ${SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}    
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libzlib.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libbase64_neon64.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libbase64.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libbrotli.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libcares.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libgtest_main.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libgtest.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libhistogram.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libicudata.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libicui18n.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libicutools.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libicuucx.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libllhttp.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libnghttp2.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libnghttp3.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libngtcp2.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libnode.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libopenssl.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libtorque_base.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libuv.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libuvwasi.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_base_without_compiler.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_compiler.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_init.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_initializers.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_libbase.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_libplatform.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_snapshot.a
 ${NODE_DIR}/out/Release/libv8_zlib.a
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
 ${INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Our `main.cpp` is exactly the [example embedding application](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/HEAD/test/embedding/embedtest.cc) from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/embedding.html).

Compiling yields a single linker error which reads:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"node::SnapshotBuilder::GetEmbeddedSnapshotData()", referenced from:
node::GenerateAndWriteSnapshotData(node::SnapshotData const*, node::InitializationResult const) in libnode.a(node.o)
node::LoadSnapshotDataAndRun(node::SnapshotData const*, node::InitializationResult const) in libnode.a(node.o)
node::worker::Worker::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) in libnode.a(node_worker.o)
node::contextify::ContextifyContext::ContextifyContext(node::Environment*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, node::contextify::ContextOptions const&) in libnode.a(node_contextify.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Undefined symbol: node::SnapshotBuilder::GetEmbeddedSnapshotData()
```

We do not understand how to solve that error and cannot find any hints. Could it have something to do with `NODE_WANT_INTERNALS` not being defined, which would cause the `SnapshotBuilder` class to be missing (defined in `node_snapshot_builder.h`)?

Edit: We're on Mac Monterey

Answer (score 0):

You might want to build Node.js without Node.js’s own snapshot. Pass `--without-node-snapshot` to `configure`.

```
./configure --without-node-snapshot
make -j4
```

Comment: We added this option, but the error unfortunately stays exactly the same...
We're on Mac Monterey btw